# pythonからweiboの投稿を取得したいですがTypeErrorが出る。

Tags: python

下記のプログラムを使って、pythonからweiboの投稿を取得したいです。

```
from weibo import Client

API_KEY = '294703483' # app key
API_SECRET = 'a2ef9de0a580edb7a26daf2804d27624' # app secret
REDIRECT_URI= 'https://api.weibo.com/oauth2/default.html' # callback url

c = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI, token="2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE", username="USER", password="PASSWORD")

class Client(object):
   def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret, redirect_uri, token=None,
   username=None, password=None):
 # const define
        self.site = 'https://api.weibo.com/'
        self.authorization_url = self.site + 'oauth2/authorize'
        self.token_url = self.site + 'oauth2/access_token'
        self.api_url = self.site + '2/'
```

実行結果

```
[root@localhost デスクトップ]# python cinco.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cinco.py", line 7, in <module>
    c = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI,
token="2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE", username="USER", password="PASSWORD")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weibo.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.set_token(token)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weibo.py", line 84, in set_token
    self.uid = token['uid']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

下記のリンクからweiboとpythonの情報取得しました。
[http://weibo.lxyu.net/　（weiboのドキュメント）](http://weibo.lxyu.net/%E3%80%80%EF%BC%88weibo%E3%81%AE%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%EF%BC%89)

[https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lingwang/weiboguide/　（weiboのaccess_tokenについて）](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Elingwang/weiboguide/%E3%80%80%EF%BC%88weibo%E3%81%AEaccess_token%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%EF%BC%89)

上記のリンクで収得した内容

```
{"access_token":"2.00skPOWG0zpXw_e8253b9b7c9GKIdE","remind_in":"157679999","expires_in":157679999,"uid":"5973036902”}
code=682ac33cecf21d6efee0882e2a91eba4
```

[https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO　　　　　　　　　（pythonからweiboの投稿を取得について）](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO%E3%80%80%E3%80%80%E3%80%80%E3%80%80%E3%80%80%E3%80%80%E3%80%80%E3%80%80%E3%80%80%EF%BC%88python%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89weibo%E3%81%AE%E6%8A%95%E7%A8%BF%E3%82%92%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%EF%BC%89)

http://open.weibo.com/apps/294703483/info/basic (API_KEYなどの情報が載っています）

もしわかる方いれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4):

エラーメッセージの中でポイントとなるのは

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weibo.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.set_token(token)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weibo.py", line 84, in set_token
    self.uid = token['uid']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

というあたりですが、文字列に対する添え字は数値でなければならず、 `token['uid']` といった文字列キーでのアクセスができないというものです。要するに、 `Client(...)` に指定する `token` は `{"access_token":"...","remind_in":"...","expires_in":...,"uid":"...”}` に対応するような辞書型であり、**access_token の文字列ではありません**。

ドキュメントに書かれた次のコードのように、既存のClientから取得したものを使うのが正しいです。

```
token = c.token
c2 = Client(API_KEY, API_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI, token)
```

WeiboのAPIを呼び出すうえでは確かに access_token だけあればいいのですが、お使いの [lxyu/weibo](https://github.com/lxyu/weibo) では access_token のみの設定ができないようです。
<sub>見たところaccess_tokenしか使っていないので、他の要素を適当に設定した辞書を渡せば動きそうではありますが。</sub>

当然ライブラリによって異なりますから、同じく質問に書かれた [michaelliao/sinaweibopy](https://github.com/michaelliao/sinaweibopy/wiki/OAuth2-HOWTO) の方では access_token のみの設定が可能なようですが、今**お使いのとは別のライブラリです**。念のため書いておくと、どちらも公式のライブラリではありません。

Comment: ご返事ありがとうございました。